# How to resolve hidden dependency with interface

Tags: .net, unit-testing, interface

I have a code, where chessboard and piece are injected with interfaces. DiagonalDirections is enumeration. So far, so good. I don't inject dependencies, neither I use hidded dependencies.

```
private void addToAllowedPositions(IChessboard chessboard, IPiece piece, DiagonalDirections direction)
    {
        int horizontalIndex = piece.Position.IndexHorizontal;
        int verticalIndex = piece.Position.IndexVertical;
        while (AreIndexesValid(setHorizontalIndexDirection(direction, ref horizontalIndex), setVerticalIndexDirection(direction, ref verticalIndex)))
        {
            IPosition currentPosition = new Position(horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
            IPiece currentPiece = chessboard.GetPiece(currentPosition);
            if (currentPiece == null)
                 {
                     allowedPositions.Add(currentPosition);
                 }
            else if (currentPiece.Color != piece.Color)
                 {
                     allowedPositions.Add(currentPosition);
                     break;
                 }
                 else break;
         }
    }
```

Problem is with this line of code:

```
IPosition currentPosition = new Position(horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
```

I really don't know how can I use interface here? New Position must be created each time. That is my only dependency, which I don't know how to isolate. I also have a problem, when I want to unit test this piece of code. If anything is changed in Position class, it is immediately being reflected also in this method, on existing unit tests.

Comment: You could use a factory to create the new position. is `Position` a POCO?

Comment: Yes it is. Only two propertis - horizontal and vertical. How to use factory? Perhaps you have example?

Comment: instead of creating position manually in method you delegate the creation out to something else. you can either create a new factory service whose sole job is to create positions or you can have a factory method on one of your existing interfaces. Some one answered already that you could have a factory method on the chessboard interface to create the position.

Comment: Wouldn' that mean (method for creating positions on already existing interface) that I would couple chessboard and Position?

Comment: If you don't that association between the two then create a dedicated interface to create the position. (single responsibility). but that would mean either injecting service via method or constructor. you have options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a factory method to the `IChessboard` interface:

```
IPosition currentPosition = chessboard.CreatePosition(horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean a dependency between chessboard and Position?

Comment: The chessboard implementation chooses which implementation of `IPosition` to return, whether it's the standard `Position` class or something else, but if `IPosition` is just a pair of numbers and has no actual behavior, it doesn't really need to be an interface.